# C++ automatically generate wrapper for boost::make_shared

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am using boost shared pointers extensively, so I'm creating a class with a bunch of useful/ common functionality. As part of this, I want to create static member functions that wrap around boost::make_shared to allocate/ construct instances of the object. For example, if class A has the constructor:

```
class A {
  A(int arg1, double arg2);
  ...
}
```

Then the corresponding wrapper around make_shared would look like this:

```
class A {
  A(int arg1, double arg2);
  static boost::shared_ptr<A> MakeShared(int arg1, double arg2) {
    return boost::make_shared<A, int, double>(arg1, arg2);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then to create an instance, you just do:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr = A::MakeShared(1, 2.3);
```

Clearly the relationship between the constructor and MakeShared is very mechanical, so my question is whether/ how it is possible to create a preprocessor macro or base class which can automatically make a version of MakeShared available for each constructor? So that the code just looks something like this:

```
class A {
  A(int arg1, double arg2);
  A(int arg1, double arg2, bool arg3);
  ...
  DEFINE_CORRESPONDING_MAKE_SHARED_FUNCTIONS
  ...
}
```

Using the boost preprocessor libraries (or other libraries) is fine, but the larger project isn't ready to use C++11, so hopefully we can avoid that.

Comment: Is this really needed? make_shared can deduce types so make_shared<A>(1, 2.3) works fine.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that make_shared can deduce types- I was trying to avoid having to do something like make_shared<A, int, double>(1, 2.3), which isn't too bad for 1 or 2 arguments, but gets very tedious and cumbersome for more arguments and/or more complex types. How do you make functions/ templates able to deduce arguments like that? As a point of general interest, I'd like to know how to write my own functions that do that.

Comment: never mind- I just looked it up and all you have to do is use the template parameter in the arguments and then it can be omitted from the angle brackets. ie `template<class T> void f(T arg);` can be called with `int i = 1; f(i)` which is equivalent to `f<int>(i)`. I just didn't know about that little feature of C++. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved for a pre-defined number of arguments:

```
#define DEFINE_MAKE_SHARED_FUNCTIONS(CLASS_TYPE) \
  template<typename A1> \
  static boost::shared_ptr<CLASS_TYPE> make_shared( const A1& a ) {\
      return boost::make_shared<CLASS_TYPE>( a );\
  }\
  template<typename A1,typename A2> \
  static boost::shared_ptr<CLASS_TYPE> make_shared( const A1& a, const A2& a2 ) {\
      return boost::make_shared<CLASS_TYPE>( a, b) );\
  }
```

If you want to get fancy you can use boost preprocessor to automate the macro, but you could just as easily implement all N versions in one macro (probably compile faster).

You could use veridic templates to reduce the need for a macro, but at the moment that is not portable (no VC++ support).

Also, I question the need for this as make_shared(args...) works all by itself.

Comment: You still haven't realized you are trying to use the this pointer in a static member function.